# Cannot use apache flink in amazon emr

Tags: hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr, apache-flink

I can not a start a yarn session of Apache Flink in Amazons EMR. The error message I get is

```
$ tar xvfj flink-0.9.0-bin-hadoop26.tgz
$ cd flink-0.9.0
$ ./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 4 -jm 1024 -tm 4096
...
Diagnostics: File file:/home/hadoop/.flink/application_1439466798234_0008/flink-conf.yaml does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/hadoop/.flink/application_1439466798234_0008/flink-conf.yaml does not exist
...
```

I am using Flink verision 0.9 and Amazons Hadoop version 4.0.0. Any ideas or hints?

The full log can be found here: https://gist.github.com/headmyshoulder/48279f06c1850c62c28c

Comment: What happened before the error? Could you please share more of the output?

Comment: Ok, I added the complete log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the log:

> The file system scheme is 'file'. This indicates that the specified Hadoop configuration path is wrong and the sytem is using the default Hadoop configuration values.The Flink YARN client needs to store its files in a distributed file system

Flink failed to read the Hadoop configuration files. They are either picked up from the environment variables, e.g. HADOOP_HOME, or you can set the configuration dir in the flink-conf.yaml before you execute your YARN command.

Flink needs to read the Hadoop configuration to know how to upload the Flink jar to the cluster file system such that the newly created YARN cluster can access it. If Flink fails to resolve the Hadoop configuration, it uses the local file system for uploading the jar. That means that the jar will be put on the machine you launch your cluster from. Thus, it won't be accessible from the Flink YARN cluster.

Please see the [Flink configuration page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/setup/config.html#hdfs) for more information.

edit: On Amazong EMR, `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf` let's Flink discover the Hadoop configuration directory.

Comment: Some of the configuration files are in /etc/hadoop/conf other not. I point in the flink configuration to this directory but it does not change anything.

Comment: Can you execute the `env` command to see if the environment variables are set? Also, did you put `fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /etc/hadoop/` in the Flink configuration file? Does /etc/hadoop contain the Hadoop xml configuration files?

Comment: `HADOOP_HOME` is not set. `/etc/hadoop/conf` contains some of the configuration files, but not all. For example, it cotains `hdfs-site.xml` but not `hdfs-default.xml`. According to flinks documentation these two files are needed.

Comment: Can you execute `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf` and try again?

Comment: You're welcome :) Putting `fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /etc/hadoop/conf` in the Flink config should also work.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the for me too the export was the solution to the problem

Answer (score -1):

if i were you i would try with this:

> ./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 1 -jm 768 -tm 768